# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm getting the following error code when trying to create a test user. The program runs fine until I click "Continue", which is the button that is supposed to create the user using Firebase.

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbf2e6e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fa5e9b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbf2cac +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Messenger                           0x000000010d56584e +[FIRAuth auth] + 110
    4   Messenger                           0x000000010d555efa $s9Messenger22RegisterViewControllerC20registerButtonTapped33_FFE3ECCAB97030FD54B85ADB55404ED2LLyyF + 2394
    5   Messenger                           0x000000010d55666b $s9Messenger22RegisterViewControllerC20registerButtonTapped33_FFE3ECCAB97030FD54B85ADB55404ED2LLyyFTo + 43
    6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000114443c19 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113df2b6a -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113df2eb2 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 396
    9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113df1e23 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 497
    10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113fcc345 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 9331
    11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113fc9e94 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 467
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113fc9c1c -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:] + 225
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000114481273 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4479
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000011445b6cd -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001144e64ca __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 7628
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00000001144e968e __handleEventQueueInternal + 6584
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00000001144dff31 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 88
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb56c91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb56bbc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb56394 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb50f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 974
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb508a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011a3c8bbe GSEventRunModal + 139
    24  UIKitCore                           0x0000000114442964 UIApplicationMain + 1605
    25  Messenger                           0x000000010d55c62b main + 75
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001122c21fd start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I also get this message in AppDelegate even though I did put in FirebaseApp.configure():

```
Thread 1: Exception: "The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift)."
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a beginner so sorry/let me know if I didn't include enough information. Thanks.

Comment: Going forward, please include the code that throws the error; that's often times more important than the error trace. Best practice; add a breakpoint and run the app. If it works up to that breakpoint then that code is probably ok. Then move the breakpoint further along and try again. If it crashes before the breakpoint, keep backing it up until you closely pinpoint the line that's crashing and include that line and surrounding code in the question. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase must be configured before the Auth API is called to create the user.

`FirebaseApp.configure()` should be called in the app's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

See detailed instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize-firebase.